# What strategy should I use to approach this problem? If my straight line approximation doesn't work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

recently i wrote an assignment in one of the questions i got two different answers for the same question by considering a straight line motion

**The question was somewhat like this**

**THIS IS A HOMEWORK QUESTION AND I AM NOT ASKING THE EXACT ANSWER I JUST WANT GUIDANCE**

> A particle is thrown obliquely with a velocity of $15\sqrt{5}$ $metres$ $per$ $second$ and 45 degrees to the horizontal. $100$ meters from the point of projection starts stairs in which each step is $1$ meter in height and $1$ meter in width. Keeping this in consideration, which step should the particle hit?

I calculated the horizontal range of this projectile from the formula
$$R=\frac{u^2\sin(2\theta)}g=112.5\,m$$

prescribed value of $g$ is $10$ metres per second square

That means the particle would have to hit any one of the steps.

Proceeding forwards with the formula of 
$$x \tan\theta\left(1-\frac{x}R\right)=y$$
where $x$ is the horizontal displacement of the particle and $y$ is the vertical displacement.

Through which I can calculate its height, $y=11.111$, and as we know that the remaining horizontal distance to be covered by the particle before coming to the level of point of projection is $112.5-100=12.5$ 
by constructing a right angled triangle like this

**I know that particle won't travel a straight path in the influence of gravity, but as the distance is not too far from it's final point we can consider its path to be straight for some time.**

[image]

as the point will be at the midpoint of rectangle and making the rectangle into four triangles

By Pythagorean theorem, we get the hypotenuse in every triangle as $8.35 meters$ then the point where they meet is approximately 8.35 meters on the line of stairs.

[image]

By converting this value into steps i.e. as we know one step measures $\sqrt{2}$ then for 8.32 it would be $5.883128419$ $meters$. Therefore, it would hit the wall of fifth step.

**But would this approximation be correct as we considered a straight line motion of the particle so would it hit 5th step or 6th step**

**how can I look at the problem and others like it so that I can imagine and formulate a solution on my own?**

i just have an idea of pythagorean theorem tosolve this and nothing else

Comment: why is this downvoted??

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing a question here. You use formulae without explaining what they pertain to - what is $u$, what is $r$? Your velocity has no units. And what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @ACuriousMind here $u$ refers to initial velocity of projection and $r$ refers to horizontal range of projectile

Comment: I think you want to find the intersection of your equation for the motion of the projectile (assuming it's correct...) with the equation of a line starting 1 foot before you have the line in the diagram - meaning, "at the top of each step" instead of at the bottom. Then you can be sure of which step you land on.

Comment: @levitopher i din't get you . i basically don't have any mathematical background so these things are somewhat new to me

Comment: i have edited my question by displaying how i got the point where the line of trajectory meets the steps

Comment: There is something wrong with your diagram. Since there is no air resistance, the path of the particle would hit the horizontal at 112.5 m and an angle of 45°. Also, you should use 9.8 m/s for gravity since it will move the distance to 114.8 m.

Comment: @LDC3 am i wrong in any other concept in this issue

Comment: @ACuriousMind  why is this off-topic????  i have shown all of my efforts and i have asked for a particular physics concept to come to a conclusion

Comment: My comment above still stands. I'm not seeing a real question here. What *specific* concept have you asked for? Andrew Ross' answer below is as good an answer as you can desire, since he shows you all the equations and thinking needed without solving it for you. If you want more, you are, in my opinion, *definitely not* asking for a concept.

Comment: @ACuriousMind i want a mathematical concept to come to a conclusion that which step will the ball hit and if i am wrong about that then please let me know

Comment: I am sure you mean well, but all of your edits just switch around/remove/add superfluous parts of your question. You have not yet improved the main reason for closure: That you are asking about a particular solution to a particular problem, that *anyone* could solve with basic kinematics. The "concept" you are missing is: *"Write the curve of the ball as $y(x)$ and find its intersection with the curve describing the steps."* Everything else is straightforward computation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the thing is that i live in hyderabad a city in telangana state of india where we have maths only upto 10th standard i just cannot understand what you want to say about the curve can you please make me understand that concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using g = 10 m/s, and the provided information, I get the following:
[image: Projectile Location]
This means the projectile would strike between 6 and 7 meters and end up on the step that is 6 meters from the ground.

Equations:
For $x_i$, I select the values between 100 and 112 inclusive.
For y, the equation is
$$y_i=x_i\cdot tan(\theta )\cdot \left (1-\frac {x_i}{x_{max}}\right )$$
Using 112.5 m for $x_{max}$.

Comment: can you please provide the equation through which you got this table i do not have a strong mathematical background

Answer (score 1):

One potential way of going about finding which step you hit is the following. You can parameterize the motion of the particle in the plane by $(x(t), y(t))$, where $t$ is time and $x$ and $y$ are as follows,

$$y(t) = y_i + (v_i)_yt - \frac{g}{2}t^2, \quad x(t) = x_i + (v_i)_x t.$$

Fortunately we can kill the parameter $t$, via the substitution $t = \frac{x - x_i}{(v_i)_x}$ into the left equation above. Doing so yields (taking $x_i = y_i = 0$):

$$y = (v_i)_y \frac{x}{(v_i)_x} - \frac{g}{2}\left(\frac{x}{(v_i)_x}\right)^2.$$

Because of symmetry, $(v_i)_y/(v_i)_x = 1$. Thus, we have

$$ y = x - \frac{g}{2(v_i)_x^2}x^2,\tag{1}$$

Where we've written the height $y$ as a *quadratic* function of the horizontal distance $x$.

Now consider the line touching the top of the stairs and the line touching the bottom of the stairs (like the one in your picture) given by the equations

$$ y = x - 99 \quad \text{and} \tag{2}$$
$$ y = x - 100,\tag{3}$$

respectively. Now by solving for $x_1$ such that $(1) = (2)$ (taking the positive solution) and solving for $x_2$ such that $(1) = (3)$ (again taking the positive solution) you can deduce which step you hit. That is if there exists $n$ such that $n \le x_1 < x_2 \le n + 1$, then you hit the $(n - 99)$th step, and if there exists $n$ such that

$$n-1 < x_1 < n < x_2 < n+1$$

then you hit the vertical piece after the $(n - 100)$th step. Also, notice that since $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 - \frac{g}{(v_i)_x^2}x = 0$ for $x = \frac{(v_i)_x^2}{g} = (15\sqrt{5/2})^2/9.8 \approx 57m$, we know that after roughly $57m$ the particle is "falling" and thus we must have one of the above two cases.

Comment: i am unable to understand your derivation of ${(2)}$ and ${(3)}$

Comment: This answer is very close to what my comment was getting at. The equations (2) and (3) are the equations of the lines touching the steps. You have in your diagram equation (3); equation (2) is parallel to the steps but touches the upper corner of each step rather than the lower corner, which (3) does. You "derive" them with the equation for a line $y=mx+b$, where $m=1$ and there are two different $y$-intercepts, $-99$ and $-100$.